# facing the issue Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am running a simple selenium problem below:

```
package FirstPackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class DemoClass 

{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\amitS\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Script\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://myhotel.staging-privatedeal.com/en");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }


    }

}
```

And here is my error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

    at AmitProjectOne/FirstPackage.DemoClass.main(DemoClass.java:12)
```

I want to open a chrome browser only

Comment: This exception means that your source code is not valid and Eclipse could not compile all of it. The good news is: Eclipse will show you in the source editor exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Eclipse should be showing you errors - fix them before trying to run the code. Looks like you have mismatched brackets.

Comment: Remove that extra closing curly brace.